# Mogrify command removing the wrong side of image

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation, mogrify

```
magick mogrify -chop 0x450+0+0 -gravity South -auto-orient *.jpg
```

also

```
mogrify -crop +0-45 +repage *.jpg
```

To my mind, these should remove the bottom 450px of an image taken on my camera.

For landscape, it worked. For portrait, it removed the left-hand side of the image.

I then tried to use -gravity East, and this seems to have removed a part of the middle of each landscape image....

Any idea what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: Try putting the `auto-orient` **before** the `-crop` or `-chop` so the image is correctly orientated before chopping.

Comment: Make sure you put the gravity setting before the operation that uses it, like `... -gravity South -chop 0x450 ...`.